# Delphi - Command to clear all TEdit

Tags: delphi

I have many TEdit. Is there any command to clear all TEdit without manually clearing it like doing this

```
edit1.clear;
edit2.clear;
```

I don't prefer doing that because i have a lot of fields .. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to loop through controls of your Form or container to clear them all.

There are several ways to achieve that.

The Form is the Owner of all components placed on it at design-time. You can loop through all Form components to clear them:

```
procedure ClearEdits(Owner: TWinControl);
var i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Owner.ComponentCount - 1 do
    if Owner.Components[i] is TEdit then TEdit(Owner.Components[i]).Clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClearEdits(Self);
end;
```

Another approach is to loop through a Parent container (can also be a Form), but in that case you have to clear the edits recursively, because the Parent holds only its immediate children in a list of controls.

```
procedure ClearEdits(Parent: TWinControl);
var i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Parent.ControlCount - 1 do
    begin
      if Parent.Controls[i] is TEdit then TEdit(Parent.Controls[i]).Clear
      else
      if Parent.Controls[i] is TWinControl then ClearEdits(TWinControl(Parent.Controls[i]));
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClearEdits(Self);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClearEdits(SomePanel);
end;
```

Comment: Very helpful .. Thank You!

Answer (score 5):

The other answers have you looping through Parent/Owner containers looking for the `TEdit` controls dynamically.  While that does work, it has some overhead to it every time you want to clear the `TEdit` controls.

You should instead add the desired `TEdit` controls to an array or `TList` one time at Form creation, and then you can loop through that array/list when needed. That will be faster, less overhead, and more accurate than hunting for the controls dynamically.

```
private
  MyEdits : TList;

procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyEdits := TList.Create;
  // fill list as needed...
end;

procedure TMyForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyEdits.Free;
end;

procedure TMyForm.ClearEdits;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to MyEdits.Count - 1 do
    TEdit(MyEdits[i]).Clear;
end;
```

When filling the array/list, you could add the `TEdit` controls individually:

```
procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyEdits := TList.Create;
  MyEdits.Add(Edit1);
  MyEdits.Add(Edit2);
  MyEdits.Add(Edit3);
  ...
end;
```

Or you can use a loop similar to what the other answers show, eg:

```
procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  MyEdits := TList.Create;
  for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
    if Components[i] is TEdit then
      MyEdits.Add(Components[i]);
end;
```

Or you can even override the Form's `Notification()` method to detect when each `TEdit` is created:

```
procedure TMyForm.Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Operation = opAdd) and (AComponent is TEdit) then
  begin
    if MyEdits = nil then MyEdits := TList.Create;
    MyEdits.Add(AComponent);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
procedure TFormMain.ClearAllEditFields;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ControlCount -1 do
  begin
    if Controls[ i ] is TEdit then
    begin
      (Controls[ i ] as TEdit).Clear;
    end;
  end;
end;
```